# Azure App Service with User-Assigned Managed Identity crashes application

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-appservice

I have both a VMSS and multiple AppServices I would like to use the same User-Assigned Managed Service Identity. For the VMSS, I am able to assign the identity and use it to retrieve secrets from the Azure Key Vault with the following code:

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(KeyVault), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var secret = client.GetSecret("secret-name");
```

The AppServices use ASP.NET Core 3.1, and so [the recommended way](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/427dc3d2961c5272ff816c5128fb6c0c40dd7ce8/aspnetcore/security/key-vault-configuration/samples/3.x/SampleApp/Program.cs#L75) to access Key Vault secrets is:

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider("RunAs=App;AppId={client id for the user-assigned managed identity elided}");
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
config.AddAzureKeyVault("https://{my vault name}.vault.azure.net/", keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
```

Note the connection string is derived from the 'User-assigned identity for Azure resources' scenario in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support).

The above code snippet throws the following exception:

> 2020-08-27T02:06:18.409648197Z Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Connection string RunAs=App;AppId={client id ellided} is not valid. Must contain 'TenantId' attribute and it must not be empty.
> 2020-08-27T02:06:18.409681697Z    at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderFactory.ValidateAttribute(Dictionary`2 connectionSettings, String attribute, String connectionString)
> 2020-08-27T02:06:18.409688597Z    at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderFactory.Create(String connectionString, String azureAdInstance)
> 2020-08-27T02:06:18.409693297Z    at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider..ctor(String connectionString, String azureAdInstance)
> 2020-08-27T02:06:18.409697797Z    at API.Program.<>c.b__1_0(HostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder config) in /tmp/8d84a2d16145d21/API/Program.cs:line 25
> 2020-08-27T02:06:18.409703497Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
> 2020-08-27T02:06:18.409707797Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()

When I add the 'TenantId' as requested, the message changes to:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Connection string RunAs=App;AppId={client id elided};TenantId={tenant id elided} is not valid. Must contain at least one of CertificateStoreLocation or AppKey attributes.

The managed identity does not have a certificate, and I am trying to use MSI to avoid adding secrets to code or appsettings.

I have tried removing the 'AppId' and 'TenantId' part of the connection string as per the 'Managed identities for Azure resources' scenario which results in the following exception:

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: RunAs=App, Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/b905ac32-5779-4bab-ac34-a8445e89f9e4. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. MSI ResponseCode: BadRequest, Response: {"statusCode":400,"message":"Unable to load requested managed identity.","correlationId":"c8409322-357a-49d0-9686-453fb37cc4b4"}

I assume it's trying to load the non-existing system-assigned identity. I have confirmed that Managed Identity is configured for the (Linux) WebApp instance through the Kudu console:

```
  Kudu Remote Execution Console Type 'exit' to reset this console.
  /home>env
  MSI_ENDPOINT=[Managed identity has been configured. This value is not viewable in Kudu but is exposed to the app.]
  IDENTITY_ENDPOINT=[Managed identity has been configured. This value is not viewable in Kudu but is exposed to the app.]
  IDENTITY_HEADER=[Managed identity has been configured. This value is not viewable in Kudu but is exposed to the app.]
  MSI_SECRET=[Managed identity has been configured. This value is not viewable in Kudu but is exposed to the app.]
```

Is there an issue with MSI+AppService+Linux, or the documentation, or both, or the code samples, or the configuration, or my code?

Comment: instead of setting this in the code itself, can you try to add `AzureServicesAuthConnectionString` as an App Setting (just the client id, without the tenant info)? thats how I'm running my apps

Comment: Thanks for this tip! I did not know this setting could be added to app settings. The only mention of `AzureServicesAuthConnectionString` says to set it as an environment variable.

Comment: @silent or @simonhaines, how exactly do you get this to work as an app setting? I have tried adding `AzureServicesAuthConnectionString` (in the appsettings root) and `ConnectionStrings:AzureServicesAuthConnectionString`, but it does not get picked up. (I can gauge this because if `RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=AzureCli` is picked up, there is no delay, but without it, there is a 5-10 second startup delay.) It works as an environment variable or connection string inserted from code, but not as an app setting.

Comment: "If you want to use a user-assigned managed identity, you can set the AzureServicesAuthConnectionString application setting to RunAs=App;AppId=<clientId-guid>. Replace <clientId-guid> with the client ID of the identity you want to use." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#asal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication is no longer recommended to use with new Key Vault SDK. It is replaced with new Azure Identity library DefaultAzureCredentials available for .NET, Java, TypeScript and Python and should be used for all new development. More information can be found here: [Authentication and the Azure SDK](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/authentication-and-the-azure-sdk/).**

The VMSS code you posted is using the new KeyVault SDK which is fine.

But for App Service, since you are still on the legacy SDK (assuming by looking at your code), please check if you have the latest stable nuget of [Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/) explicitly added to your project (assuming you continuing with the legacy SDK for now).

Also, I hope you have already added User Assigned Identity in the App service blade.

[image]

Comment: So I guess the real issue here is that when the documentation says that **Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication is no longer recommended** it really means **cannot be used** or **will throw exceptions**, and nobody has told the documentation writers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-managed-identities-for-azure-resources) or updated the code samples [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/427dc3d29/aspnetcore/security/key-vault-configuration/samples/3.x/SampleApp/Program.cs).

Comment: Using the KeyVault SDK also has issues: `Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials` and `ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed. Status: 400 (Bad Request)`.

Comment: Old SDK (1st comment): No, not recommended does not mean it will throw error! Did you read my full answer where I mentioned to update the nuget Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication to latest version (version < 1.4 had bug).

Comment: New SDK (2nd comment): To use user managed identity with DefaultAzureCredential, you need to set ManagedIdentityClientId property.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#specifying-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-with-the-defaultazurecredential

Comment: Thanks, why is the ManagedIdentityClientId property required here, and not for VMSS?

Comment: I think VMSS is automatically assigning when you have a single identity attached. But App service is not. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/11400

Comment: Hmm OK, looks like there are still a few more wrinkles around this feature. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Krishg : THanks a lot!!!!! Updating to 1.4 helped me. You are unsung hero!!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication?view=azure-dotnet), the legacy `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` library only supports User-Assigned Managed Identity in App Services/Function Apps via 'connection string support'.

This can be as simple as setting the environment variable `AzureServicesAuthConnectionString` to:
`RunAs=App;AppId={ClientId of user-assigned identity}`